# Is the use of ellipses... rude?

Tags: politeness, ellipses

Coming from the UK and in my experience in writing to people on-line, it seems that some cultures that use the English language do not understand that ellipses in communication can come across as sarcastic or gloomy, or a variety of other feelings that usually feel negative to the reader.

I’m sure I’m not alone when I say this but I usually find *dependent on content but most of the time coming across as negative* that the use of ellipses in instant messaging is rude.

What is the bottom line? I hope there is an answer to this...

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Comment: Sorry, no... I can think of too many examples for this...

Comment: A few representing examples, not all of the examples you know of.

Comment: Surely this is enough... there's just too many. The scope of this question is not dependent on the context.

Comment: I can think of a few different usages. Some as you used - which seem out of place, some which skip irrelevant info and some which are used to shorten long lists. So... no. I do not think that examples are redundant.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the brains nor the examples, my question cannot be refined by myself in any more detail, and I'm not about to poach personal conversation into question

Comment: "Ellipses" meaning three dots like this: "..." ?  I never thought of that as negative or rude.

Comment: Yes. Okay, well that is your opinion - I want to avoid this question being closed as discussion so thanks for commenting but I'm looking for answers with either solid reasons as to why I could be right or wrong

Comment: If you are unwilling to provide examples, I'm voting to close the question. This question is too vague to have an answer as it stands. Certainly you can use ellipses in ways which are rude, but you can also use ellipses in ways which are completely unexceptional. And if you're expecting Americans to guess what U.K. English speakers find rude and avoid those things, you are not going to get very far (especially if these Americans are not IMing from the U.K.).

Comment: do u find some1 using bad orthogriffy rude 2 u 2?  if so, this mite splain it.

Comment: If you are used to reading books written with craft instead of text messages by ten-year-olds, it can be jarring to the point of perceived rudeness to suddenly confront a piece of English text that doesn’t meet the standard of Standard English. When all commas, semicolons, and full stops are replaced by ellipses, the entire paragraph is either ALL CAPITALS or else all lowercase, and words rgllrly abbv8td in inconsistent and puzzling ways, it gets under your skin. And things that get under your skin may be perceived as rudeness, even though they aren't meant to be. My guess it's that it's this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may read about the *ellipsis* in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

You will note that nowhere in that discussion does it mention that the ellipsis should be avoided due to rudeness.

In fact most of the discussion there is about how to properly format the ellipsis rather than how to avoid it-  This is telling in my book.

I think that you should re-evaluate your reaction to the ellipsis.
To quote Inigo Montoya, "*I do not think it means what you think it means.*"